# Looking for details on the PixelOffsetMode Enumeration in .Net, WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, graphics

The possible values of `PixelOffsetMode` are:

```
Invalid  
Default  
HighSpeed  
HighQuality  
None  
Half
```

I'm guessing that HighQuality = Half, HighSpeed = None and Default = HighSpeed.

If this is true then, like the `SmoothingMode`, I can offer just two simple options.

Does anyone know if this is correct and, if so, where on earth did you find the information?

Comment: Any news about this? Its really odd that the default mode cuts 0.5 pixel of the first column after scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If this is true then, like the SmoothingMode, I can offer just two simple options.

Your assumption seems to be correct.

According to this excellent [page/blog](http://photosauce.net/blog/post/image-scaling-with-gdi-part-3-drawimage-and-the-settings-that-affect-it) about Graphics.DrawImage:

> [Those docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode(v=vs.110).aspx) make it clear; there are really only two options, and the
>   Remarks section describes quite nicely what each does. The real
>   options: None and Half. The rest are just aliases for those two. I’ll
>   make it even simpler: None=Bad, Half=Good. The default value is Bad.

[The GDI+ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534169(v=vs.85).aspx) actively explains that there are actually only two options:

> PixelOffsetModeNone Indicates that pixel centers have integer coordinates.
>
> PixelOffsetModeHalf Indicates that pixel centers have coordinates that are half way between integer values.

Invalid is never to be used, and the other values simply link through to the ones mentioned above.

So in summary, *although* the enumeration has different values:

None == Default == HighSpeed, yielding a lower quality but faster operation, pixels usually do NOT represent the color value of their integer location (i.e. their corner)

Half == HighQuality , yielding better results (less artifacting) but in a costlier operation, after all pixels usually represent the value of their center.

Answer (score -1):

`PixelOffsetMode` is defined as:

```
public enum PixelOffsetMode
{
    Invalid = -1,
    Default = 0,
    HighSpeed = 1,
    HighQuality = 2,
    None = 3
    Half = 4,
}
```

A great way to see these values (and other similar things) is to use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: Hi, I know the values of the enumeration but I want to know how they are converted for the out of framework call. For instance if you look at SmoothingMode, there are many values but it basically boils down to two options - Antialias or not. I think this will boil down to Offset by Half or don't offset.