# What is the motivation behind PixelOffsetModeHighSpeed and PixelOffsetModeHighQuality?

Tags: windows, graphics, gdi+

I do quite a bit of manual GDI+ drawing in C# and was always annoyed by the apparent (0.5, 0.5) pixel offset that GDI+ uses by default (my mind is more compatible with the IMO simpler definition of (0, 0) being the upper left corner of the upper left pixel). Until recently I thought it was probably just a stupid .NET thing to make things """easier""" - I just translated by (-0.5, -0.5) before doing anything else. Until I stumbled upon the `PixelOffsetMode` enum.

[.NET definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode.aspx) | [C API definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534169.aspx)

```
typedef enum  {
  PixelOffsetModeInvalid       = QualityModeInvalid,
  PixelOffsetModeDefault       = QualityModeDefault,
  PixelOffsetModeHighSpeed     = QualityModeLow,
  PixelOffsetModeHighQuality   = QualityModeHigh,
  PixelOffsetModeNone          = QualityModeHigh + 1,
  PixelOffsetModeHalf          = QualityModeHigh + 2 
} PixelOffsetMode;
```

It seems that the "off by (0.5, 0.5)" is a deliberate GDI+ thing.

There are also these 2 answers on SO:

[Looking for details on the PixelOffsetMode Enumeration in .Net, WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427343/looking-for-details-on-the-pixeloffsetmode-enumeration-in-net-winforms)

[What is PixelOffsetMode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441479/what-is-pixeloffsetmode)

The answer to the latter question seems to be subtly incorrect as well. There is no difference between `HighQuality` and `Half` (which is the mode that puts the origin in the upper left corner of the upper left pixel, and `HighSpeed` and `None` (which puts the origin in the center of the upper left pixel). The documentation of the C API enum definition even confirms this.

What bugs me most is, even though 2 of the options contain the words "Speed" and "Quality", which value you choose has nothing at all to do with speed or quality, it's just a different definition of the coordinate system used for drawing. Both can produce the exact same result with the exact same speed. In practice, this is very obscure and knowing the precise location of the origin is crucial for writing correct drawing code - vague terms like "Quality" or "Speed" aren't helpful here. Using the incorrect enum value doesn't make the drawing slow or low-quality, it simply makes it wrong.

Yet someone must have come up with those enum values when GDI+ was developed and may have thought of a reason for `HighQuality` and `HighSpeed` to exist. I'd like to know that reason - maybe there is a subtle difference, or there used to be a difference but it's not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the motivation but I can make a guess.

GDI is very old API, and that thing appeared in Windows 2000. The recommended hardware requirements for that OS say Pentium II 300MHz, 128 MB RAM, minimum is Pentium 133 MHz, 32MB RAM. By today’s standards, that’s *extremely* slow hardware. Very likely, that’s why you aren’t observing any differences in rendering speed on a modern Windows PC.